# Design pattern for creating a website debug pane

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

When debugging a web application, console logging can only go so far, especially if you want to monitor many different things. In most games, a special debug screen can be produced which monitors many different attributes of the game, but I haven't seen anything like this for websites.

Example: http://www.minecraft.gamepedia.com/Debug_screen

Is there a pattern for creating this type of screen? ie. What key combo normal to use, what attributes are normally included, etc.

Comment: The browser's developer tools already let you monitor a bunch of stuff beyond simple console logging. You can step through the JS code line by line (and/or set break points), fiddle with css styling, etc. What else is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: For example, I would like to keep track of the ping to the server. The way I was doing it before in the console was to just print the ping out a bunch of times. It would be better for me if the ping was displayed as a constantly changing number or maybe a graph somewhere on the screen in a 'hidden' section.

Comment: You can determine the the length of time a request take using the network tab of your favorite browsers dev tools. Chrome for exmaple has great profiling for all sorts of things, like load times, JS execution, CSS3 animations. To see where your performance hitches are. Game engines are multi-threaded, multi-task environments. Websites aren't